# Problems with DIV Tags in Html/Css

Tags: css, html

I've been trying to create a website but the `div` tags aren't seeming to go as planned. For the banner `div`, logo `div` and main navigation system `div`, they are perfectly in line where I want them, but when I try to position the subnavbar and the search bar, they go in a weird position? I can't see what I've done wrong with my code, it all seems okay.

Basically for the subnav bar I want it underneath the `logo div`, and then for the `search div`, I want this slightly under the main navigation system.
The code is below to make things easier, Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/xyDt2/

I believe here is the code I am having problems with:

html

```
<div id="SubNavBar">
<a id="LaptopsOver" href="#" class="left" > </a>
<a id="NetbooksOver" href="#" class="left" ></a>
<a id="TabletsOver" href="#" class="left" ></a>
<a id="eRaaderOver" href="#" class="left" ></a>
</div>
```

css

```
#SubNavBar {
border: 3px solid #000;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: 209px;
width: 100px;
left: auto;
right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code here along with your fiddle. Also, please try to follow the site guidelines and not circumvent them. There is a reason you can't post a jsfiddle link unless there is code in your question...

Comment: It's all on jsfiddle, It's just the subnavbar div + the searchbar div

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, I didn't see the problem with it, thought it would be easier, sorry about that sir.

Comment: Yeah just erase the space and will work

Comment: Anyone got any suggestions? Please :[, It's really bugging me, and I ain't got a clue how to fix it

Comment: Maybe you should solve the issues mentioned by @War10ck first.

Comment: the link to fiddle doesn't work

Comment: updated it now, I want to position that code in the sort of 'centre' of the site, underneathe my logo

Comment: `"Basically for the subnav bar I want it underneath the logo div"..` Currently you have deliberately (?) centered your subnav bar, so obviously it will not be underneath your logo, which is on the left. You have set 'left: auto' and 'right: auto', which basically centers the element. Do you have a wireframe (image) of how you want your site to look like?

Comment: Ahh right, I'm kind of new to web creation, but I see what that means now, thanks, so how would I get it under the logo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyDt2/4/) (sample part below)

```
#SearchBar {
position: absolute;
/*margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;*/
margin:auto;
height: 30px;
width: 900px;
/*top: auto;
left: auto;
right: auto;*/
```

}

Look at the commented out css.

Edit:
In the final version I also added a wrapper to contain everything and I removed the empty `<p></p>` to remove the white line above the subnav.

Margin-right and margin-left: auto can be shortened to margin:auto;
Also no need for positioning and left, top, bottom properties. float and position:absolute don't work together.

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped a lot, the searchbar is now in the position I want it, I'm still having problems with my subnavbar though, any suggestions? Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah like that, apart from I want it so when you zoom in/out on the website, the search bar and subnav stay in position

Comment: Glad I could be of help, I clarified my answer to better indicate the changed parts.

Comment: Yeah thanks for that, I've got a much better understanding of the margin's etc too now which is of good use, and the wrapper idea kind of was the main solve to my issue, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When you float all the elements inside a `div`, the height of that `div` collapses to zero and the element that follows it is at the mercy of the floated sub-elements.

The quickest way to fix this, add `overflow: auto` to the container(s):

```
#Banner, #SearchBar, #SubNavBar {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/xyDt2/6/

A more comprehensive solution is to add a [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) to each of the container `div`s, but `overflow:auto` should be sufficient for modern browsers.

Comment: Not really the type of thing I'm looking for though, I don't like them scroll boxes on the website, thanks for your reply though :)

Answer (score 1):

Your markup on the fiddle was missing a close brace after the `#eReaderOver:hover`

what was:

```
#eReaderOver:hover
{ 
background: url("Images/SubNavBarOver_04.gif");
```

should be:

```
#eReaderOver:hover
{ 
background: url("Images/SubNavBarOver_04.gif");
}
```

And you were missing a semicolon after the position line in that fiddle as well:

so what was:

```
#SearchBar {
position: relative
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: 30px;
width: 900px;
top: auto;
left: auto;
right: auto;
 }
```

should be:

```
#SearchBar {
 position: relative;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: 30px;
width: 900px;
top: auto;
left: auto;
right: auto;
 }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing that out, my searchbar works now, that must have been a big part of the error, I still can't fix the positioning of the subnavbar though, any suggestions? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

because you use  tag for make your  background! it cause push another divs to the bottom. i think all you need is like this:

```
<div id="Banner">
 <div id="Logo"></div>
   <div id="NavBar">  
     <a id="ReviewsOver" href="#" class="Right" ></a>
     <a id="ContactOver" href="#" class="Right" ></a>
     <a id="ShopOver" href="Shop.php" class="Right" ></a>
     <a id="HomeOver" href="Index.php" class="Right" ></a>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="SearchBar">
  <form action="./Results.php" method="get" class="Right"> 
    <input type="text" name="input" size="50" style="border:3px solid #000" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </form> 
</div>

<div id="SubNavBar">
  <a id="LaptopsOver" href="#" class="left"> </a>
  <a id="NetbooksOver" href="#" class="left"></a>
  <a id="TabletsOver" href="#" class="left"></a>
  <a id="eRaaderOver" href="#" class="left"></a>
</div>
```

and make your CSS like this:

```
#Banner {
border: 5px solid #000;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: 100px;
width: 900px;
left: auto;
right: auto;
    background: url('images/Banner.gif') top right no-repeat;
}
#Logo {
border: 2px solid #000;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
left: auto;
top: auto;
right: auto;
    background: url('images/logo.gif') top right no-repeat;
    float: left; /* if you want to put logo in left of banner, else write right */
}
#SearchBar {
position: relative
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: 30px;
width: 900px;
top: auto;
left: auto;
right: auto;
    float: right;
}
#SubNavBar {
    border: 3px solid #000;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height: 209px;
width: 100px;
left: auto;
right: auto;
    float: left;
}
```

you can floating your objects in the page by "float" atribute in css, try it!

Comment: I gave this a go, doesn't really work properly as the logo over-laps my banner etc, and the navbar has some how now gone to a weird location, Thanks for your help though, Appreciated! :)